# C++ Compiler error in inherited template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting a C++ compiler error that I don't understand and haven't been able to find
a fix or an explanation for. Here is a code snippet demonstrating the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class A {
public:
  A(int n) {data = new T[n]; }
  const T &operator()(int i) const {return data[i];}
protected:
  T *data;
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
  B(int n) : A<T>(n) {}
  T &operator()(int i) {return this->data[i]; }
  //const T &operator()(int i) const {return this->data[i];} // fixes problem
};

template<class T, int N>
class C : public B<T> {
public:
  C() : B<T>(N) {}
private:
};

template<class T>
void doOp(const T &v) {
  std::cout << v(0) << std::endl;
}

void templateTest()
{
  C<double, 3> c;
  c(0) = 5;
  std::cout << c(0) << std::endl;

  doOp(c);
}
```

If I un-comment the line in class B, the code compiles and executes correctly but I
don't understand why defining this operator function in class B is any different from
the definition in class A.

Thanks for the help.

Bill

Comment: and what is the error message? don't you think it might be relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `doOp()` is invoking a non-`const` member function through a reference to `const`.

If you uncomment the commented line, a viable `const` member function will be found, and overload resolution will pick that version of the call operator.

Without uncommenting that line, the inherited version of the call operator is not found because it is being **hidden** by the overloaded call operator in the subclass.

To illustrate the problem of name hiding with a simpler example, consider the following program:

```
struct X
{
    void foo() { }
};

struct Y : X
{
    void foo(int) { }
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.foo(42); // OK
    y.foo(); // ERROR! Name hiding...
}
```

The compiler here won't be able to resolve the call to `y.foo()`, because `X::foo()` is being hidden by `Y::foo()` here.

To fix the problem, you could add a `using` declaration in `Y`:

```
struct X
{
    void foo() { }
};

struct Y : X
{
    using X::foo;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    void foo(int) { }
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.foo(42); // OK
    y.foo(); // OK
}
```

Now both function calls are correctly resolved. In your program, you could add a similar `using` declaration for `operator ()` of the base class:

```
template<class T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B(int n) : A<T>(n) {}
    T &operator()(int i) {return this->data[i]; }

    using A<T>::operator();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the simple example and the fix! I had obviously forgotten about overloaded functions in base classes being hidden. But after you pointed it out to me, I see this behavior is clearly explained in e.g. Lippman's book. ;-( Thanks again for the help. Bill